# I used 3 containers encapsulated by a stack to get layout something similar like this, now I want to make the page scroll able?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

Whenever I use any scrollable Widgets like single child scroll view but it throws a renderflex overflowed error. In the below code I am trying to use layout builder to get the scroll view. Any other suggestion, how can I get the scrollable view? I don't want any animation while scrolling now do I want appbar, I just want the normal scrolling option.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final article args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
return new LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: viewportConstraints.minHeight,
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 300.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("images/image.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  left: 40.0,
                  right: 40.0,
                  top: 240.0,
                  bottom: 40.0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 500.0,
                    width: 300.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            "Title",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 100),
                        Text(
                          "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
          )));
});
```

}

The error is as follows:

```
I/flutter ( 8759): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY

 ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8759): The following message was thrown during layout:

I/flutter ( 8759): A RenderFlex overflowed by 134 pixels on the bottom.

I/flutter ( 8759): 

I/flutter ( 8759): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of 
Axis.vertical.
```

Comment: What is the value of `viewportConstraints.minHeight`? Try putting `print` statement to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 500.0,
              maxWidth: 300.0
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          "Title",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 100),
                      Text(
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I want to make the whole page scrollable rather than the middle container only. Can you help me with it?

Comment: What do you mean with the while page? do you want the height and width of the card to be as big as the screen size? or do you mean so that the app bar disappears, when you scroll?

Comment: Nothing to do with the app bar, I just want the whole page scroll and I was able to figure that out. Thanks for all the help. Cheers!